# Trying to Create Github Repo using curl

Tags: git, github

I'm following the guide @ https://developer.github.com/guides/getting-started/ got stuck at https://developer.github.com/guides/getting-started/#create-a-repository

when I run

```
curl -i -v -H "Authorization: token ##############################" -H -d @create.txt https://api.github.com/user/repos
```

Here is create.txt:

```
"{   "name":"blog",
    "auto_init":true, 
    "private":true,
    "gitignore_template":"nanoc"
      }"
```

This is the result:

```
   Trying 192.30.253.116...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to api.github.com (192.30.253.116) port 443 (#0)
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* Cipher selection: ALL:!EXPORT:!EXPORT40:!EXPORT56:!aNULL:!LOW:!RC4:@STRENGTH
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: C:\Curl\ca-bundle.crt
  CApath: none
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS header, Certificate Status (22):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server key exchange (12):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server finished (14):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client key exchange (16):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS change cipher, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS change cipher, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* SSL connection using TLSv1.2 / ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256
* ALPN, server accepted to use http/1.1
* Server certificate:
*  subject: C=US; ST=California; L=San Francisco; O=GitHub, Inc.; CN=*.github.com
*  start date: Apr  8 00:00:00 2014 GMT
*  expire date: Apr 12 12:00:00 2017 GMT
*  subjectAltName: host "api.github.com" matched cert's "*.github.com"
*  issuer: C=US; O=DigiCert Inc; OU=www.digicert.com; CN=DigiCert SHA2 High Assurance Server CA
*  SSL certificate verify ok.
> POST /user/repos HTTP/1.1
> Host: api.github.com
> User-Agent: curl/7.51.0
> Accept: */*
> Authorization: token ###########################################
> Content-Type: application/json
> Content-Length: 100
>
* upload completely sent off: 100 out of 100 bytes
< HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
< Server: GitHub.com
Server: GitHub.com
< Date: Mon, 05 Dec 2016 09:31:43 GMT
Date: Mon, 05 Dec 2016 09:31:43 GMT
< Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
< Content-Length: 87
Content-Length: 87
< Status: 404 Not Found
Status: 404 Not Found
< X-RateLimit-Limit: 5000
X-RateLimit-Limit: 5000
< X-RateLimit-Remaining: 4985
X-RateLimit-Remaining: 4985
< X-RateLimit-Reset: 1480931012
X-RateLimit-Reset: 1480931012
< X-OAuth-Scopes: gist
X-OAuth-Scopes: gist
< X-Accepted-OAuth-Scopes: public_repo, repo
X-Accepted-OAuth-Scopes: public_repo, repo
< X-GitHub-Media-Type: github.v3
X-GitHub-Media-Type: github.v3
< Access-Control-Expose-Headers: ETag, Link, X-GitHub-OTP, X-RateLimit-Limit, X-RateLimit-Remaining, X-RateLimit-Reset, X-OAuth-Scopes, X-Accepted-OAuth-Scopes, X-Poll-Interval
Access-Control-Expose-Headers: ETag, Link, X-GitHub-OTP, X-RateLimit-Limit, X-RateLimit-Remaining, X-RateLimit-Reset, X-OAuth-Scopes, X-Accepted-OAuth-Scopes, X-Poll-Interval
< Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
< Content-Security-Policy: default-src 'none'
Content-Security-Policy: default-src 'none'
< Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubdomains; preload
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubdomains; preload
< X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
< X-Frame-Options: deny
X-Frame-Options: deny
< X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
< X-GitHub-Request-Id: 7BED4AC8:15602:174E4027:584533FE
X-GitHub-Request-Id: 7BED4AC8:15602:174E4027:584533FE

<
{
  "message": "Not Found",
  "documentation_url": "https://developer.github.com/v3"
}
* Curl_http_done: called premature == 0
* Connection #0 to host api.github.com left intact
```

I am new to Git and StackExchange :).

Am I missing the trick with create.txt?

Thanks you for your time.

Comment: I never used GitHub API, but from api docs (not guides) it looks like you are missing **OAuth scope**. Without the scope it's supposed to be a read-only access => leads to an error. See [create api (OAuth rquirements)](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/#oauth-scope-requirements).

Comment: GitHub docs suggest you can't do that yet: https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/#create "(Currently not enabled for Integrations)"

Comment: @IrLED I defined the OAuth scope while creating the token, is that it?..

Comment: From this `< X-OAuth-Scopes: gist |
X-OAuth-Scopes: gist |
< X-Accepted-OAuth-Scopes: public_repo, repo |
X-Accepted-OAuth-Scopes: public_repo, repo` the OAuth you use has scope `gist`. You need to create/configure OAuth token to have the scope of `repo` or/and `public_repo`

Comment: @bcmcfc@IrLED.. Well turns out I was using the wrong Access Token.. appreciate the quick response..thanks. @IrlED

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [GitHub OAuth api doc](https://developer.github.com/v3/oauth/#scopes)

> Check headers to see what OAuth scopes you have, and what the API
>   action accepts.
>
> ```
> curl -H "Authorization: token OAUTH-TOKEN" https://api.github.com/users/technoweenie -I
> HTTP/1.1 200 OK
> X-OAuth-Scopes: repo, user
> X-Accepted-OAuth-Scopes: user
> ```
>
> X-OAuth-Scopes lists the scopes your token **has authorized**.
>   X-Accepted-OAuth-Scopes lists the scopes that the action **checks for**.

Your token is authorized for `gist`

```
< X-OAuth-Scopes: gist
X-OAuth-Scopes: gist
< X-Accepted-OAuth-Scopes: public_repo, repo
X-Accepted-OAuth-Scopes: public_repo, repo
```